# Why does swearing 'turn the air blue'?

Tags: expressions, idioms, offensive-language

Why do we say that the air is blue when someone has been swearing a lot?

Comment: [The use of “blue” to describe something profane dates from around the 1800s, but the origins of this use of the word are a bit unclear.](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-blue-talk.htm) I doubt you'll get much more info than what's on that link.

Comment: [There's another question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/605875/what-is-the-origin-of-the-term-blue-movie) about the term blue movie, which is probably related.

Comment: I would note that when metals are heated with a torch, they first turn red, then white, then blue, as they get hotter.

Comment: Flatulence burns blue.

Answer (score 9):

The association of "blue air" with cursing has been around since at least the 1880s. Farmer & Henley, *Slang and Its Analogues* (1890) offers this brief entry:

> To MAKE THE AIR BLUE, *phr[ase]*, (popular). To curse; to swear; to use profane language.

Farmer & Henley then sends the reader off to look at its entry for sense 2 of the adjective *blue*, which is as follows:

> Indecent; 'smutty'; obscene. this may be derived from the blue dress of harlots ... although Hotten suggests it as coming from the French *Bibliotheque Bleu*, a series of books of very questionable character.

But a somewhat different association may also have been at work in the original association of cursing with "blue air"—namely, the blueness of smoke-filled air, of the sort one might see on a battlefield or in a region of eternal fire and brimstone. To such effect is this excerpt from "[A Rose of Glenbogie](https://books.google.com/books?id=jWgoAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA203&dq=%22air+was+blue+wi%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DTx3Vb_XGMn8oQTGsYGwBw&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22air%20was%20blue%20wi%22&f=false)," written in the mid-1880s(?) by Bret Harte:

> "The puir man [a minister] consented—although he dinna ken why and wherefore—and preached a gran' sermon! Ay, man! it was crammed wi' denunciation and an emptyin' o' the vials o' wrath! The congregation sat dumb as huddled sheep—when they were no' starin' and gowpin' at the meenester's wife settin' bolt upright in her place. And then when the **air was blue** wi' sulphur frae tae pit, the meenester's wife uprises!"

Something similar is going on in G. H. Emerson, [*Life of Alonzo Ames Miner*](https://books.google.com/books?id=OUqAVTEh3xwC&pg=PA465&dq=%22air+was+blue+and+every+syllable%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=eTx3VbiGFce0ogSgz4CoBw&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22air%20was%20blue%20and%20every%20syllable%22&f=false) (1896):

> Any attempt to portray Dr. Miner as a Melanchthon would be preposterous. It would deceive no one, and would revolt his friends as a grotesque disfigurement. No, in every drop of his blood he was a Luther; and in Luther's day with Luther's thought he would have gone o the Diet of Worms, and had he been confronted "by as many devils as there were tiles upon the house-tops," even the devils would have trembled, even if they had not believed. When aroused, not doubting that he was battling with a foe that meant only evil, he knew no honeyed words, no arts of indirection, no compromising accents. Literally he flamed, the "**air was blue**," and every syllable was a missile that struck home.

Both "the meenester" in Hart's story and Dr. Miner (a Universalist minister) in real life are unlikely to have stood in their pulpits and filled the air with four-letter words; so it seems probable that "turning the air blue" had, as one possible meaning, loosing a cannonade or fusillade of excoriating denunciation such that the meeting place seems filled with blue smoke afterward.

The first instance that a Google Books search finds of "blue air" being used in connection with cursing involves a snatch of collegiate doggerel titled "[Geological](https://books.google.com/books?id=N88iAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA214&dq=%22startled+air+is+blue%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=CD13VZyOOofqoAS01KHABA&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22startled%20air%20is%20blue%22&f=false)" from *The [Williams College] Argo*, volume 15 (February 16, 1884), reprinted from an earlier appearance in *The [Yale] Record*:

> A stratum of solid, slippery ice;/A stratum of slush so soft and nice;/A stratum of water; over that/A stratum of man in a new silk hat;/Above, the startled **air is blue**/With oath on oath a stratum or two.

The most common source (other than cursing) of "blue air" from a colorless predecessor in 19th-century references is pipe smoke, but other possibilities are also mentioned.

Anna Cumming Miller, [*The Myrtle Wreath, or, Stray Leaves Recalled*](https://books.google.com/books?id=j8U-AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA342&dq=%22the+very+air+is+blue%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Nz93VbzFDpLEogS7hILYCw&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22the%20very%20air%20is%20blue%22&f=false) (1854), nominates cold:

> There are not so many storms, but everybody you meet will say, "it is bitter cold"—the very **air is *blue***—you can see it and feel it, though it moves not—it is heavy and still, and presses upon you like a weight.

H. Prescott Beach, "[Shore-Bird Shooting in New England](https://books.google.com/books?id=kJNAAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA457&dq=%22air+was+blue+with+smoke%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pz93VY_XHM3poATR6YHgCw&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22air%20was%20blue%20with%20smoke%22&f=false)," in *Outing: Sport, Adventure, Travel, Fiction*, Volume 20 (September 1892) cites gun smoke:

> In the midst of this we opened fire, and while the frightened denizens wildly circled in uncertain flight around us, we loaded and reloaded many times. The **air was blue** with smoke, and quivered with the shrill cries of the willets, the scared whistle of the plover, the squeaking call of sandpipers, and, over all, the thunder of the guns.

Frank S. Pinckney, [*The Tarpon, or "Silver King"*](https://books.google.com/books?id=BHcUAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA65&dq=%22air+is+blue+with+yells%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BEB3Vf3-FcPxoAThlYH4Bg&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22air%20is%20blue%20with%20yells%22&f=false) (1889) suggests raucous noise without profanity:

> I let him [the fish] run 100 ft, when I strike, and out comes the fourth member of this royal family, amid the whoops and yells of all the interested spectators. Listen to the shouts. "Hurrah for Olds! Bully for Kinney! Go it, S------! Oh, that leap! Look at him fly! Give him the tip! Great guns! I wouldn't have missed this for any money." The remaining boats begin to scatter to give us room, while the **air is blue** with yells and war whoops. The splash after splash which alone can be heard a mile away, as each fish comes out in his turn—words cannot describe such a scene. It must be seen and heard to be understood.

Perhaps an offshoot of this sense is the sense "rife," as in this quotation from Alice Elinor Bartlett, [*A New Aristocracy*](https://books.google.com/books?id=jzziAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA255&dq=%22air+is+blue+with+reforms%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OEB3VZafBIbKogTfvoCwCQ&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22air%20is%20blue%20with%20reforms%22&f=false) (1891):

> "I am afraid I'm a heathen," he said dubiously, " if in this day and age, when the **air is blue** with reforms, I object to seeing the girl I love wearing her life away for a mere chimera."

H. K. Stroud, "[System for the Sales Manager](https://books.google.com/books?id=zPRKAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA181&dq=%22turn+the+air+blue+around+him%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0EB3VcPyHYn6oQTRw4HACQ&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22turn%20the%20air%20blue%20around%20him%22&f=false)," in *Ad Sense: Devoted to the Interests of Buyers of Advertising* (September 1905) puts in a vote for suppressed heat:

> He is very apt to receive an indignant phone call, calculated to raise all his ire, but his answer must be courteous and pleasant, while his inner feelings are hot enough to **turn the air blue** around him.

And "[The Show Life in America](https://books.google.com/books?id=AVJNAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA60&dq=%22guaranteed+to+turn+the+air+blue%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XkF3VdnnJ5DWoASCioPYBw&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22guaranteed%20to%20turn%20the%20air%20blue%22&f=false)," in *The Showman: An Illustrated Journal for Showmen and All Entertainers* (October 4, 1901) implies prurience or lewdness:

> Some shows are very coarse, such as the "beauty shows," and a weird dance known as the "hootche kootche," which is guaranteed to **turn the air blue** for a mile around, where they are exhibited.

Yet other early references to turning the air blue have a jokey element, as in this one from Florence Howe Hall, [*Social Customs*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ApAWAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA27&dq=%22said+to+turn+the+air+blue%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qUF3Vc2gJoHYoAT7uILYCA&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22said%20to%20turn%20the%20air%20blue%22&f=false) (1887):

> It is interesting to note that according to Buddhist tradition the first lie was told by a king, and was therefore no doubt a white, or society lie. The citizens who heard it were even more innocent than George Washington. He, at least, knew what a lie was, even if he didn't know how to tell one; but these poor people were utterly ignorant on the subject, and asked whether a lie was white, black, or blue! It is to be feared that the blue lie has disappeared from the face of the earth, unless it survives in that kind of swearing which is said to **turn the air blue**.

And this one by K.F.R., from [*The [Cornell University] Cornellian*](https://books.google.com/books?id=S7o0AQAAMAAJ&q=%22I+smoked+no+more+the+air+was+blue%22&dq=%22I+smoked+no+more+the+air+was+blue%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=D0J3VfiKONPooATVtrPgDg&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA) (1891), which brings together "blue from smoke" and "blue from swearing":

> Musing, I sat smoking a pipe,/In reverie deep till the **air was blue**;—/My father came, alas! too true,/I smoked no more. The **air was blue**.

To sum up, we have instances between 1854 and 1905 in which blue air seems to be ascribed to cold, to suppressed heat, to pipe smoke, to gun smoke, to a general rifeness, to prurience, to raucous (but not profane) noise, to angry (but not profane) denunciation, and to cursing.

---

**Update (July 7, 2020): Early newspaper instances of "turn the air blue"**

I checked the Elephind newspaper database to see whether very early instances of "turn the air blue" consistently appeared in the context of cursing. The evidence seems to support this connection.

From "[A Word to Voters](https://virginiachronicle.com/cgi-bin/virginia?a=d&d=TWDR18690901.1.1&e=-------en-20--1--txt-txIN-%22turn+the+air+blue%22-------)" in the *Wheeling [West Virginia] Daily Register* (September 1, 1869):

> Is your name on the registration lists? If not, have it placed there at once. Your township registrar declares that he is willing to enroll you when you satisfy him you are qualified. Call upon him at once. Don't neglect the matter and **turn the air blue** with curses in October.

From "[Concerning Army Chaplains](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83030214/1878-07-13/ed-1/seq-3/#words=%22turn%2Bthe%2Bair%2Bblue%22)" in the *New-York Tribune* (July 13, 1878):

> The words used [by Colonel Steedman] in my defence would not look well in print. One of the mildest epithets that the Colonel applied to the agent was "thief." The man ventured to defend himself. Then came the words: "You stole my chaplain's trunk, and I order you at once to deliver it over to him, and if I hear another impudent word from you I will put you under arrest." He said he would relinquish it, but "under protest." The stream of bad words that fell from the lips of the good Colonel seemed to **turn the air blue**, and actually made me feat sorry that I had said anything about my lost treasure. It Is needless to say that I recovered the trunk and have it yet.

From an [untitled item](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn95073194/1881-09-14/ed-1/seq-2/#words=%22turn%2Bthe%2Bair%2Bblue%22) in the *Columbus [Nebraska] Journal* (September 14, 1881), reprinted from the *Lincoln [Nebraska] Globe*:

> The amenities of Chicago daily papers will soon pass into proverb. The *Joemedillian* and *Billstorean* force whack each other over the head with their journalistic shillalies, and **turn the air blue** with their expressive epithets. Meanwhile the *Inter Ocean*, towering above both the com[b]atants, gives soothing advice only to be hooted at by both.

From "[Kimball Defeats Sexton for $1,000](https://idnc.library.illinois.edu/cgi-bin/illinois?a=d&d=NYC18820506.2.25&e=-------en-20--1--img-txIN-%252522turned+the+air+blue%252522--------)," in the *New York Clipper* (May 6, 1882):

> When they discovered that they were virtually an eighth of a mile away from the billiard-table, they rushed to exchange seats, which cost them from fifty cents to one dollar additional. This helped to fill the balcony, balcony-boxes and parquet; but it **turned the air blue** at the same time, and was damaging to all billiard-matches in the immediate future.

In each of these early instances, the sense of the usage is that actual or fancied cursing caused or would cause the air to turn blue.

Answer (score 0):

The OED is uncertain of the origin of the term ‘blue’ with reference to pornography, swearing etc.; see below.

> ### Etymology
>
> <sub>[...]</sub>
>
> #### *Semantic history*.
>
> <sup>[...]</sup>
> The origin of sense [A. 10](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/20577?rskey=wgMuY5&result=1&isAdvanced=true#eid17811325) is uncertain. Quot. [1818 at sense A. 10a](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/20577?rskey=wgMuY5&result=1&isAdvanced=true#eid233356973) suggests a connection with the blue flame of burning brimstone (as characteristic of hell), but it is not entirely certain that this quot. shows continuity with the later use. Perhaps compare [blue gown n. 1(a)](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/20598#eid253881289), although this appears to have been current only in a rather earlier period. A suggested connection with French *bibliothèque bleue*, denoting literature in a blue paper cover sold by itinerant sellers from the 17th to the 19th centuries and read by the lower social classes, seems unlikely, since such material appears in general to have been highly moral in tone.

Comment: Your quotation of the OED is hard to read without A. 10, Quot. 1818, or A. 10a. :P

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement to [Sven Yargs's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/137341/466641),  Sulfur is the element that makes black powder (a.k.a. gunpowder)  burn blue. Sven Yargs made good references as to why the turn of phrase would reference smoke/haze/air because of battlefields and burning things.  But he didn't address why the color was blue and not some other.  It was probably the use of sulfur in the explosives of the time. Sulfur-based gunpowder could have literally turned the air blue.  From there, we could logically make the jump -> explosives = blue (literally) = "explosive" language or content = blue figuratively.

Comment: Hello Lezlie. I think that the blue haze rather than the blue flame is a more likely source (as is given in Sven yargs' answer). Notice how detailed and supported by evidence his answer is; that makes it a good answer (though not necessarily the correct explanation).

Comment: Haze (and say cigarette smoke) 'is often blue' as the blue wavelengths of white light are selectively scattered [ [University of Illinois](http://ww2010.atmos.uiuc.edu/%28Gh%29/guides/mtr/opt/air/blue.rxml) ]

Comment: Yeah, I did a crappy job of making my point.  I wan't trying to argue with Sven Yarg.

Comment: Your 'answer' is a good 'comment' by ELU standards. But you have to reach the magic 50 rep points mark before you're allowed to comment. There must be a reason why it's that way round, but I've never known what it is. // If you look at Bob's answer, you will see that he stated two years ago that OED mentions your theory as being a possibility, but that it claims no more than that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a 1872 use of the expression in the Appleton's Journal. I don't have the original version with me right now but the translation I did to Spanish. Will post the original as soon as possible. It was used in the sense of cursing until the air got blue. I like the Sulphur hypothesis because we use in Spanish "to sulphurate" to indicate getting angry.

Comment: Whose *sulphur* hypothesis? Sven Yargs's or Lezie Moore's *sulfur*?

Answer (score 0):

Turning the air blue, which seems to have [first appeared in print](https://www.google.com/books/edition/University_Chronicle/IUHiAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22turning+the+air+blue%22&pg=RA14-PA1&printsec=frontcover) in 1867, has its roots in *blue streak* (1830 Kentucky slang), which refers to a bolt of lightning — a sudden, shocking, and bluish burst.

Working our way backwards, let’s look at the *OED* (with its earliest example usages quoted here):

> **blue**, *adj.* and *n.*
>
> **PHRASES**
> **P8.** ***to turn (also make) the air blue***: to swear profusely, to use obscene language (cf. sense A. 10b).
>  <sub>1867    
> *Chronicle* (Univ. Michigan) 9 Nov. 1/3     If a crowd of ‘roughs’ go careering through the streets at midnight, turning the air
> blue with curses.</sub>
>  <sub>1887     *Frank Leslie's
> Pop. Monthly* 23 278/2     Then came shouts from all
> directions..mingled with curses enough to make the air blue.</sub>

Here is A. 10b as referenced:

> **A.** *adj.*
>  II. Extended uses.
> **10.** *colloquial*
> **b.** Of language: characterized by obscenities; coarse or offensive. Cf earlier *blue streak* *n.* at Compounds 1d.
>  <sub>1832
>     Q. Rev. Mar. 65      A choice specimen of the
> blue talk of Cincinnati.</sub>
>  <sub>1871     R. D.
> BLACKMORE *Maid of Sker* i, in *Blackwood's Edinb. Mag.* Aug. 141/1
>    A villanous Frenchman made at me with a cutlash, and a
> power of blue oaths.</sub>

Here is Compounds 1d as referenced:

> **COMPOUNDS**
> **C1.** Compounds of the adjective.
> **d.**
> **blue streak**  *n. colloquial* (originally *U.S.*)  †(*a*) something resembling a flash of lightning in speed, vividness, etc.
> (*obsolete*);  (*b*) a constant stream of words; esp. in **to talk
> (also lie, swear, etc.) a blue streak**: to talk, lie, swear, etc.,
> quickly or vigorously (cf. sense A. 10b).
>  <sub>1830    
> *Kentuckian* 14 May 2/5     To pass..with such rapidity as not even to leave a ‘blue streak’ behind him.</sub>
>  <sub>1847
>     *Knickerbocker* 30 178     Interspersing his
> vehement comments with a ‘blue streak’ of oaths.</sub>

<sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

<sub>Further reading: [What color is lightning?](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/bximjr/what_determines_the_color_of_lightning/eq98d2f/)</sub>

Answer (score -1):

This harks back to the days of official censorship in Britain. The censors were equipped with blue pencils, which they used to cross out sections of radio (later, TV) script or written articles which were considered too rude or sensitive for publication.  It's usually little remembered outside places such as the BBC or the studies of historians, but the state censors had power.

Turning the air blue is a peculiar phrase, but could refer to the airwaves of radio, or (my personal preference) the idea of a little man in a grey suit, desperately scribbling at the air itself...

Comment: 'Blue pencil' for censorship was a  WWI phrase at earliest : As Sven Yargs said, 'turn the air blue' is older than that.

Comment: Can you provide evidence for that statement, please? I'd be interested in reading your sources.