# Is Mark Twain's "Life on the Mississippi" the first to connect cursing and turning blue?

Tags: expressions

Twain's book appeared in 1883.  The penultimate sentence in chapter X, *Completing My Education*,

> These people brought up their lantern, then, of course; and as we backed and filled to get away, the precious family stood in the light of it--both sexes and various ages--and cursed us till everything turned blue?

Comment: Check Sven Yargs answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/137341/141210) for earlier examples.

Comment: @KillingTime: Why would you not VTC as dup? Clearly the answer sought here has been fully covered there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers — That doesn’t answer it. Not a dupe. Back soon.

Comment: @TinfoilHat: *Is Twain's 1883 work the first to connect cursing and turning blue?* My initial comment on the earlier Q links to [*people in the United States were certainly referencing blue talk by the 1840s,*](https://www.languagehumanities.org/what-is-blue-talk.htm) which looks to me like an answer to the OP here anyway - but Sven Yargs's excellent Answer goes in to much greater detail.

Comment: @FumbleFingers — If you reopen this, I can add the one thing missing from the “duplicate” — the etymology that ties turning the air blue (1867) to *blue streak* (1830 Kentucky slang), which refers to **lightning** — not harlot dresses, battlefields, fire, brimstone, smoke, sulfur, etc.

Comment: Actually, never mind. I'll add an answer over there.

Comment: @TinfoilHat: I think that's a *much* better idea!

Comment: Here you are: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/609790/206976 (more later).

Answer (score 0):

> Is Mark Twain's "Life on the Mississippi" the first to connect cursing and turning blue?

No. There are earlier examples:

The OED's earliest record is

> P8. **to turn (also make) the air blue: to swear profusely, to use obscene language** (cf. sense A. 10b).
>
> **1867**   Chronicle (Univ. Michigan) 9 Nov. 1/3   *If a crowd of ‘roughs’ go careering through the streets at midnight, turning the air blue with curses.*

And earlier:

> **10.** *colloquial*.  **a. Coarse, obscene; (esp. of a joke, story, film, etc.) having sexual content, pornographic.**
>
> **1818**   ‘A. Burton’ Adventures Johnny Newcome 31   *Blush, Pluto! Blush as brimstone blue! This bluer Town can boast like you A ‘facilis descensus’ too.*